# Compare and extract values from two datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
    Name    Segment   Axis    1      2      3      4      5
0  Amazon        1  slope  NaN     100     120    127    140
1  Amazon        1      x  0.0     1.0     2.0    3.0    4.0
2  Amazon        1      y  0.0     0.4     0.8    1.2    1.6
3  Amazon        2  slope  NaN     50      57     58     59
4  Amazon        2      x  0.0     2.0     4.0    6.0    8.0
5  Amazon        2      y  0.0     1.0     2.0    3.0    4.0
```

df2:

```
 Name  Segment  Optimal Cost
 Amazon   1      115
 Amazon   2      60
 Netflix  1      100
 Netflix  2      110
```

I am trying to compare the slope values in the axis column to the corresponding optimal cost values and extract the slope, x and y values.

The rule is: Find the last first slope value greater than its corresponding optimal cost

If there is no value greater than optimal cost, then report where slope is zero.

If there are only values greater than optimal cost, then report highest y value

Expected output:

```
     Name    Segment   slope   x    y     
0  Amazon        1      120    2   0.8
1  Amazon        2      NaN    0   0
```

Comment: @martineau can you help to solve this problem? or no?

Comment: The implication is that I'm not inclined to do the work I think you should have done before asking a question here.

Comment: @tj judge, it doesnt work that way on this forum. You cant change a question after the answer has been given. At least upvote for the initial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=df.set_index(['Name' , 'Segment','Axis']).stack().unstack('Axis').reset_index(level=2, drop=True)#melt dataframe 1
df3=pd.merge(s, df2, on=['Name',  'Segment'], how='left')#merge melted datframewith df2
df3[df3['slope']>df3['Optimal_Cost']].groupby(['Name',  'Segment']).first().reset_index()#Filter as required

           


Name         Segment  slope    x    y     Optimal_Cost
0  Amazon        1      120.0   2.0  0.8           115
1  Amazon        2      72.0    6.0  3.0            60
```

Comment: this works, but i made a minor change to the rules of the question

Comment: @tj judge, it doesnt work that way on this forum. You cant change a question after the answer has been given. At least upvote for the initial answer.